# Can i have something like GridView from Asp.net in Java swing?

Tags: asp.net, swing, gridview

In asp.net we can have a gridview to show , insert , update , delete columns in real time from a database connection.

Can i have something like this in java swing ?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for the basics of using tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there you can use grid-Table and jTable in swing java... following links may help you...

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/Grid-Table.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1000__JTable.htm